# C: Compiling pre-compiled code as inline

Tags: c, gcc, inlining, lto

For some rather complicated reason, I have a set of files which I would like to compile seperatly and then link, but so that the functions in one are placed inline in the second. This is because I would like them to be compiled with different flags in GCC. I know I could fix the problem by looking into how I could get around that, but I would like to know if this is possible.

EDIT 1:
If not, is it possible to compile the 'external' functions into a form of assembly that I could include in the other file. Yes crazy but also cool...

Having a quick look, this could well be an option. I guess it would be impossible to automatically compile it in, so could someone please give me a bit of information about assembly? I've only used basic ARM assembly. I've compiled to toy functions with the `-S` flag in GCC. How do I link registers with variables? Will they always be in the same order? The function will be highly optimised. When should I start and end the extract? Should I include `.cfi_startproc` at the start and `.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8` at the end?#

EDIT 2:
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987020/can-the-linker-inline-functions) details how gcc can do link-time optimisations like this with `-flto`. Sadly this is only available with version 4.5, which I do not have nor have the ability to install since I do not have root access of the machine I need to compile this on. Another possible solution would be to explain how I could install a different version of GCC into a folder on a unix machine.

Comment: EDIT 3: I've got a ball-and-chain on my leg and can't get close to the keyboard.

Comment: I think you have a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you *really* trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know gcc doesn't do [linktime optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-time_optimization) (inlining in particular), at least with the standard ld linker (it could be that the new [gold](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/gold/README?rev=1.5.2.1&content-type=text/plain&cvsroot=src) linker does it, but I really don't think so). [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) in principle should be capable of doing it, since it depends on [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [which supports link time optimizations](http://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html) (it seems that your question is gcc spacific, though).

From your question though, it seems you are looking for a a way to merge object files after compilation, not necessarily by inlining their contained functions. This can be done in multiple ways:

1. Archiving them into a static library with ar: e.g. `ar libfoo.a obj1.o obj2.o`.
2. Combining them together into a third relocatable object (ld's --relocatable option). `gcc -Wl,--relocatable -o obj3.o obj1.o obj2.o`
3. Putting them into a shared library (beware that this requires compiling the objects with -fPIC) e.g. `gcc -shared -o libfoo.so obj1.o obj2.o`

Answer (score -1):

You could compile with the -c option to create a set of .o files, or even make a .so file. Then use the sequence you like in the linking phase of gcc.

Comment: Thank you, if I called a function in the `.o` file and I was compiling with the `-finline-function` flag in GCC, would the code be inline?

Comment: This I don't know, sorry. Lets wait for other answers.