# Can small functions defined in dynamic libraries be inlined?

Tags: c, optimization, operating-system, shared-libraries

This is a follow-up to this question: [Can the linker inline functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987020/can-the-linker-inline-functions)

This time I am wondering about the same optimization, not at link time, but at run time when linking to a dynamic library. Is it possible at all? Do modern OSes do it? Why?

Comment: If a library provider intends small functions to be inlined, they can provide the definitions for such functions in the header file that accompanies the library.

Comment: Note that the method @jxh proposed should only be used if the data structures the library functions are operating on are part of the public API. If not, these inline functions will include non-public-API knowledge of the library's data structures into applications built against the library, and if a future version of the library wants to make any changes to these non-public structures, applications will badly break if used with the new version of the library. This can be dealt with by library versioning, but then you force users to keep around old versions of the libraries...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory it's possible, but there are many reasons not to do it. In practice, "dynamic linking" is not really full linking; position-independent code is used for all but the main program (and possibly the main program too), whereby the full range of relocations a full (static) linker might have to perform are not needed. Instead, only a small number of relocation types are required, which basically just amount to filling in addresses of functions and objects contained in libraries in a big contiguous table. Of course, such references in objects of static storage duration in the `.data` segment must also be filled in, so it's a little bit more work than just filling in a contiguous table, but the key point is that only data, not code, is modified.

If you start modifying code at all, you throw away most of the advantages of dynamic linking: code pages could not be shared among multiple instances of the application/library, and a lot more time would be spent at startup duplicating (via page faults and copy-on-write semantics) the mapped code pages. And this is just the minimal cost for patching a few bytes here and there in code.

For actually inlining code from dynamic libraries, what you would have to do would amount to full link-time optimization. Measure how much time it takes to LTO-link a large program, and then ask yourself if users would be acceptable waiting that long every time they start the program. The answer is almost surely no.