# Differentiate extern inline and inline in C

Tags: c, inline

I am trying to understand extern inline and inline functions.

[What's the difference between static inline, extern inline and a normal inline function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000497/whats-the-difference-between-static-inline-extern-inline-and-a-normal-inline-f)

Quoting lines from the above link:
"A function definition with just inline defines an inline function with external linkage. However, such definition is referred to as inline definition and it does not work as external definition for that function. That means that even though this function has external linkage, it will be seen as undefined from other translation units, unless you provide a separate external definition for it somewhere.

A function definition with extern inline defines an inline function with external linkage and at the same time this definition serves as external definition for this function. It is possible to call such function from other translation units."

But I am not able to understand this correctly.

I have a sample code which explains what I understood:

1. inline function:

In temp1.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
extern int32_t fun1(void);

int32_t main(void)
{
  int32_t result = fun1(); 
  return result;  
}
```

In temp2.c

```
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t fun1(void);
inline int32_t fun1(void)
{
   return 0;
}
```

Since fun1 is a inline definition in temp2.c, it will be seen as undefined from temp1.c. So external declaration in temp1.c made temp1.c to access fun1 from temp2.c. I am confused as in the quotes it is saying "separate external definition" instead of external declaration.

2. extern inline function

temp1.c

```
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t fun1(void);
int32_t main(void)
{
  int32_t result = fun1(); 
  return result;  
}
```

temp2.c

```
#include <stdint.h>

extern inline int32_t fun1(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Since fun1 is extern inline function, it can be called from temp1.c. 
The only difference what I observed is, no need of explicit declaration  of the extern inline function where it is defined.

Is it the only difference ? else what are the other major difference and the scope of inline and extern inline functions ?

Please correct if any of the above observation is wrong

Comment: That link as a case where it is not compiled because we are not declaring the function in same translation unit. But in my case I have declared and it is compiling properly

Comment: I'm using these questions (as well as the one you quoted) as guides.  [extern inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216510-inline) — [Is "inline" without "static" or "extern" ever useful in C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312597) — .
[How to declare an inline function in a C99 multi-file project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229343).  My experimentation towards writing this up is available on GitHub in my SOQ repository: https://github.com/jleffler/soq/blob/osiris/extern-inline/src/extern-inline/

Comment: Both your examples are UB as you have a function declared `inline` in one unit but not `inline` in another unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to the first, "inline function" example, you say (highlighting added to function names),

> Since `fun1` is a inline definition in temp2.c, it will be seen as
>   undefined from temp1.c. So external declaration in temp1.c made
>   temp1.c to access `fun1` from temp2.c.

Your explanation is incorrect<s>, or at least misworded</s>.  <s>In this example, your temp2.c does not provide an external definition of function `fun1()`.  The declaration in temp1.c says that there is an external definition *somewhere*, but temp2.c is not that place.  There needs to be an external definition provided by some other translation unit</s>. *Function `fun1` in temp2.c* is *an inline function because it is declared with the `inline` keyword (that's all it means to be an "inline function"), but the definition of `fun1` in that file* is not *an inline* definition, *because temp2.c contains another declaration of its identifier that does not include the `inline` keyword.  Since `fun1` is declared with (implicitly) external linkage, that is an* external *definition of `fun1`.  Anyone can call it. To get an inline definition of a function,* every *declaration of its identifier in the TU must include the `inline` keyword and must omit the `extern` keyword.*

*Standard C does require the function to be declared in temp1.c if it is to be called from that TU, but nothing you put in that file could enable code within to access an inline definition of `fun1` from a different TU.  Only external definitions are accessible across TUs -- that's what being an external definition means.*

***Note***: The original (now stricken-out) text of this part of this answer supposed that temp2.c indeed did provide an inline definition of function `fun1`, because I overlooked the flaw(?) in the declarations.

> I am confused as in the quotes it
>   is saying "separate external definition" instead of external
>   declaration.

A function definition comprises a declaration of that function, but not every function declaration is part of a definition.  We must be careful with our wording here.  There is no meaningful sense of an "external function *declaration*" in C, in that no declaration has a scope wider than its translation unit.

But one can, and often does, have (local) declarations of functions with *external linkage*.  This is the default, applicable to all function declarations that do not include the keyword `static`.  That default can be made explicit by use of the `extern` keyword, and that happens to have additional significance for declarations of inline functions.

An external function *definition*, on the other hand, is one that can be accessed by name from another translation unit.  An inline definition explicitly is not an external definition.  Thus, your first example declares that there is a function `fun1` with external linkage, but <s>does not</s> if all the declarations of that identifier carried the `inline` keyword and not `extern` then it would not provide a corresponding external definition of that function.  If that function <s>is</s> were called, even from a source file that provides an inline definition, then the absence of an external definition <s>is</s> would be an error.

---

With respect to the second, "extern inline function" example, you say (highlighting added to function names),

> Since `fun1` is extern inline function, it can be called from temp1.c.

Let's separate out the properties here.

- `fun1` is (still) declared as a function with external linkage.
- The presence of the `inline` specifier in the declaration that is part of its definition makes it an inline function.
- The presence of the explicit `extern` specifier on a declaration of that function in the same translation unit as a definition makes the definition in that TU an external one.

It is the fact that the definition in temp2.c is an external one that makes it callable from temp1.c.

> The only difference what I observed is, no need of explicit
>   declaration of the extern inline function where it is defined.

<s>There is no need for a forward declaration of `fun1()` in the first example, either.  There would be a need for a forward declaration in *both* cases if temp2.c contained a call to `fun1` prior to that function's definition.  There is no difference here.</s>

---

*Update:*

*You are more or less right.  Your two alternatives are different ways to declare an an inline function with external linkage and to provide an external definition for it.  Instead, the thing you should be comparing to, and to which the original text of this answer was erroneously addressed, would be this:*

```
#include <stdint.h>

inline int32_t fun1(void);

inline int32_t fun1(void)
{
   return 0;
}
```

*or, equivalently, this:*

```
#include <stdint.h>

inline int32_t fun1(void)
{
   return 0;
}
```

*In those cases, the provided definition of `fun1` is an inline definition, accessible only from the translation unit of temp2.c.  Of course, that's not useful unless there is code in that TU that actually calls the function.*

---

> Is it the only difference ? else what are the other major difference
>   and the scope of inline and extern inline functions ?

You are doing yourself a disservice by attempting to set up "inline" and "extern inline" as classes of functions.  There are inline functions and non-inline functions.  There are function *identifiers* with internal linkage and those with external linkage.  There are inline function *definitions*, internal ones, and external ones, and appearance of a function declaration in a TU does not necessarily require a definition in the same TU.  These combinations (and only these) of those properties are possible:

- function identifier is declared with **external linkage**, function **is not** an inline function, and an **external definition** of the function  appears in the TU
- function identifier is declared with **external linkage**, function **is not** an inline function, and **no definition** of the function appears in the TU with the declaration.  *If the function identifier is referenced in the TU then an external definition appears in a different TU.*
- function identifier is declared with **external linkage**, function **is** an inline function, and an **inline definition** of the function appears in the TU.  *If the function identifier is referenced in the TU then an external definition appears in a different TU.*
- function identifier is declared with **external linkage**, *explicitly*, function **is** an inline function, and an **external definition** of the function appears in the TU
- function identifier is declared with **internal linkage**, the function **is not** an inline function, an **internal definition** of the function appears in the TU
- function identifier is declared with **internal linkage**, the function **is not** an inline function, an **no definition** of the function appears in the TU. *The function identifier is never referenced in that TU.*
- function identifier is declared with **internal linkage**, the function **is** an inline function, an **inline definition** of the function appears in the TU

A function identifier declared with external linkage in a given TU refers refers to an external function definition, which may appear in a different TU.

A function identifier declared with internal linkage in a given TU refers refers to an internal or inline function definition in the same TU.

An inline function declaration may have either external or internal linkage, in either case, an inline definition of that function must appear in the same TU.  If the function identifier has external linkage (in that TU) and an inline function definition then it is left to the discretion of the implementation whether and where the inline definition or the (required) external definition elsewhere is used within that TU.

---

*Update:*

*Upon reflection, your characterization of functions themselves as "inline functions" and "extern inline functions" seems to reflect the idea that inline character of a function is* globally *associated with the function's identifier (e.g. `fun1`), at least for identifiers with external linkage.  This is not the case, as I hope my rather lengthy discourse has conveyed.*

*Inline character of a function identifier is a per-TU property, and inline character of a function definition is a separate, per-definition property.  If in any TU you declare a given function to be an inline function, then you must provide a definition of that function in that TU.  An external definition of a function from a different TU does not satisfy that requirement, even if the function is declared to be an inline function in the TU in which the definition appears.*

Comment: Have some difficulty in understanding correctly. In case 1: "The declaration in temp1.c says that there is an external definition somewhere, but temp2.c is not that place. There needs to be an external definition provided by some other translation unit." ..But when I compile it, the temp1.c has taken  fun1 from  temp2.c . Is there any wrong in my understanding ? "There is no need for a forward declaration of fun1() in the first example, either." When I remove the declaration it is showing "In function `main',  undefined reference to `fun1'. Can you please explain this ?

Comment: @Salim, your comment prompted me to re-examine the question and my answer, and to make substantial revisions to the analysis of your specific examples.  You should find the changes clearly marked.

Comment: So the inline function in the 1st case(having inline definition) behaves like a static inline function. Can we conclude like this if we have a inline declaration in the same TU?

Comment: Where or what way can we use effectively inline function in 1st case ?

Comment: @Salim, Yes, a genuine inline definition of a function has properties similar to those of the definition of a static function.  In particular, neither of those kinds of function definition is an external definition.

Comment: @Salim, in any given program, there can be only one external definition of any given identifier.  At the same time, if an inline function is declared in a given translation unit, then a definition of that function must appear in the same TU.  Therefore, if you have a function with external linkage, and it is declared as an inline function in two or more different TUs, then you need a way to ensure that at most one of the required definitions of that function is an external definition.  Making the others be inline definitions serves that purpose.